# How to link windows forms with treeview in C sharp

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, treeview

I’d like to make a windows form and split it in to two parts vertically.
The left side contains a tree view and the right side is empty at start.
When I click on a node of the tree list, I want the right side to open a form or panel that I already made before. So basically, the tree list nodes is just a way for me to switch through the forms in the same window without opening a new window or leaving the same window.
I already know how to make a treeview and the nodes but I’m not sure about how to make the right sides witch through the forms/panels that I made.

Comment: I want when I select one of the treeviwe options, a groupbox will appear in the right side like this example from ESET Smart Security
Ex1
http://i53.tinypic.com/2nas0uc.jpg
ex2
http://i53.tinypic.com/34hyjbl.jpg

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# .NET (WinForm) - MainForm divied on Menu (left) and Content (Right, child form)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002094/c-net-winform-mainform-divied-on-menu-left-and-content-right-child-form)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `SplitContainerControl` and add a custom UserControl to the right panel at runtime:

```
scc.Panel2.Controls.Add(new YourControl(...));
```

You could also add it in the designer and use the `Visible` property to hide it until later.

Either way, remember to set its `Dock` to `Fill`.